# JPA Entity is unknown

Tags: eclipse, persistence, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I'm tring to insert my student object to Students table in mydb database, but always get exception. However connecting to table using Connection works properly.   I'm using Eclipse with EclipseLink.

entity class

```
package student;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "studentID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "GROUPNUM")
    private String groupNum;
    @Column(name="AVGMARK")
    private double avgMark;


    public Student(){}

    public Student(String name, String groupNum, double avgMark) {
        this.name = name;
        this.groupNum = groupNum;
        this.avgMark = avgMark;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGroupNum() {
        return groupNum;
    }

    public void setGroupNum(String groupNum) {
        this.groupNum = groupNum;

    }

    public double getAvgMark() {
        return avgMark;
    }

    public void setAvgMark(double avgMark) {
        this.avgMark = avgMark;
    }

}
```

method in my class

```
package connector;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
public void insertIntoStudents(Student st) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                "students");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        // Begin a new local transaction so that we can persist a new entity
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(st);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();


    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="students" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>student.Student</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sqluser" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sqluserpw" />
    </property></properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: student.Student@62d7ef8f is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at connector.DBconnector.insertIntoStudents(DBconnector.java:60)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Comment: You should post the imports too.

Comment: Also, entities must have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: @loan  I added imports

Comment: @JBNizet Can entities have two constructors?

Comment: Yes, they can. But a no-arg constructor is needed in order for the JPA engine (eclipselink) to instantiate them.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I solved my problem by adding no-arg constructor and by changing xml file(It has mistake in this line - </property></properties>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put full name of entity in persistence xml. I mean full package name

```
package com.mycom.api.data;

@entity
public class student{

...
..
..
}
```

You should put **com.mycom.api.data.student** in persistence.xml.

Comment: my package is called student so full package name is student.Student.